# Музыкальный демон под Linux — есть ли, или как сделать?

Tags: музыка, сервер, linux

Хочу сделать веб-сервис, круглосуточно генерирующий аудиопоток, к примеру простейший синт или барабаны из трёх сэмплов по опр. алгоритму, принимая во внимание фидбэк посетителей. Не вполне представляю, с какой стороны подступиться.

Для вещания потока IceCast2 можно использовать. А вот каким инструментом генерировать алгоритмическую музыку под Linux, и как ему передавать асинхронные апдейты от посетителей?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону `ezstream`, сам недавно занимался этой проблемой.

Comment: В качестве генератора потока мне больше нравится [LiquidSoap](http://savonet.sourceforge.net/), уже подробно работал с ним.Ищу решение именно для realtime генерации алгоритмической музыки, и объединения его с очередью входящих команд через веб.